# ABPeoplePickerView - How do I get it to scroll to a selected record?

Tags: cocoa, addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I'm using the `ABPeoplePicker` in a Mac OS X application. I've hooked up a button that changes the selected record to the default 'Me' record.

This works fine, and the record gets selected, but, I need to scroll the table to see the selected record.

`NSTableView` has the `-scrollRowToVisible:(NSInteger)rowIndex` method, but I can't find anything similar for the `ABPeoplePickerView`

There is a notification `ABPeoplePickerNameSelectionDidChangeNotification` that is posted when the selected record changes, but I can't find a way of plugging in a property of the record into the view so I can make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

It will automatically scroll to your selection when using `selectRecord:byExtendingSelection:` for example:

```
[peopePickerView selectRecord:[[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me] byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

Be sure you're passing NO for the byExtendingSelection argument.

PS: Previous poster is in iPhone land ;)

Comment: I added that line to the CocoaPeoplePicker sample code and it works there.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about the scrollPersonToView method?

Comment: Isn't that only in Cocoa-Touch?

Comment: Yep; my bad: head in iPWN land… sry for the noise… ;-)